# Visual Studio Code Python Debugger Seg Fault

Tags: linux, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've installed VS Code version 1.28.1 on CentOS 7.2. Python extension is installed. Interpreter is set to Python 3.5.1 64-bit. Installed ptvsd version is 4.1.3. I'm launching vscode via putty from a Windows desktop, but essentially I'm running and debugging on the Centos system.

I've followed the python [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites) for building a simple app. When I select and run "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)", I get the following seg fault in the integrated terminal:

```
user@machine: cd /home/user/hello ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /usr/local/bin/python3 /home/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.0/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py 52056 /home/user/hello/hello.py
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Followed by a popup window with the message "Timeout waiting for debugger connection".

launch.json config:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/hello.py",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "stopOnEntry": true
}
```

I've seen the github issues but they seem dated. ptvsd.enable_attach() no longer has a "secret" keyword. I've tried adding combinations of these to the script being debugged:

```
import time
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach()
time.sleep(10)
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()
```

I've also tried several launch configs. Am I missing something here? Is this just a buggy debugger?

Comment: Have you tested that you can run the script you're trying to debug in this setup without issue? And did you install ptvsd manually (and thus build the accelerated extension module)?

Comment: Yes, the script prints "Hello World" when run without the debugger. I installed via "pip install ptvsd --pre". I haven't seen anything about an accelerated extension module.

Comment: The accelerated module is built automatically when you install yourself. Try it without your own copy installed so you use the copy that is provided in the extension. You can also report a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd .

Comment: That did it. I removed the pip installed ptvsd package and the ptvsd references in the code itself. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Same issue occurs after update to 1.29.0. Reverting to 1.28.1 did not help. Still broken.

Comment: Please file an issue on the ptvsd repo.